# jQuery mobile menu not disappearing when window size increases

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, menu, responsive

I have my jQuery mobile menu toggling as it should on small devices, but I want it to disappear when the browser reaches a certain width. It works when you refresh the browser, but doesn't as you're actually changing the browser width. I have included a link to the codepen, any help would be appreciated!

http://codepen.io/abharms/pen/rePryZ

HTML

```
       <header>    
        <div class="hamburger"><a href="#nav">&equiv;</a></div>
        <div class="logo">
           <img src="img/logo.png" alt="photographer logo">
        </div><!--end .logo-->
            <div class="">  
              <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Investment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul> 
            </div>

        <div id="mobileMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Investment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
header {
margin: 1em 0;
}
.logo {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 16%;
}
.logo img {
width: 200px;
}
.hamburger {
display: inline-block;

margin-left: 1rem;
}
.hamburger a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #7f8c8d;
font-size: 36px;
}

#mobileMenu {
display: none;
width: 96%;
}

#mobileMenu ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 20px;
}

#mobileMenu li {
padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #7f8c8d;
}

#mobileMenu a {
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #7f8c8d;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

.menu {
    display: none;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {

.hamburger,
#mobileMenu {
    display: none;
}

.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.menu {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
}
.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    font-size: .75rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right: solid 1px gray;
}
.menu li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
}
.logo img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

}
```

jQuery

```
$(".hamburger").click(function(){

if ($(".hamburger").css("display") === "inline-block" ){
    $("#mobileMenu").fadeToggle();
} else {
    $("#mobileMenu").remove();
}

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the responsive menu to hide when your resizing the browser window just add this to your jQuery.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $("#mobileMenu").hide();
})
```

Example of it working here

http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/RadwMr

Or using a media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){ 
    #mobileMenu { 
        display: none !important; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want it to hide when it reaches a certain breakpoint, not right when I start increasing the browser window. How could I do this?

Comment: You probably want to use a CSS media query to do this.

    @media screen and (max-width:600px){
        #mobileMenu {
     display: none !important;
        }
    }

Comment: THIS is what I was missing, thanks so much! I had it set to display: none but not with !important.

Comment: Excellent! Glad i could help. I'll update my answer now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try " .resize(function() " function for responsive as below:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

});
```